# Getting Bootstrap into my WordPress theme -- can't get Javascript file in

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

I've been following like a recipe book online instructions on how to add Bootstrap to a WordPress site (e.g. https://digitalfellows.commons.gc.cuny.edu/2013/11/18/learn-bootstrap-part-2-adding-bootstrap-to-wordpress/) and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm getting in the `bootstrap.min.css` but not the `bootstrap.min.js`. Any idea why that might be?

My `functions.php` includes

```
function register_and_enqueue_shit ( ) {
    wp_register_script( 'bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), NULL, true );
    wp_register_style( 'bootstrap-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css', false, NULL, 'all' );
    wp_register_style( 'fontawesome-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/font-awesome-4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css', false, NULL, 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fontawesome-css');
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'register_and_enqueue' );
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_and_enqueue_shit' );
```

and the file structure of my theme is

```
bootstrap-3.3.4-dist
   css
      boostrap.min.css
      .
      .
   fonts
   js
      boostrap.min.js
      .
      .
font-awesome-4.3.0
.
.
footer.php
functions.php
.
.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wp_enqueue_script(
        'bootstrap-js',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'
        array('jquery')
    );
```

Get rid of `wp_register_script` and try the above

Comment: No problem - glad I could help